# How to keep changes in FXML files when switching scenes

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

in our semester project we are working on world of zuul,
the problem is with the GUI part(JavaFX)
the problem is when we change "rooms" and lets say pick up an item when you go away from the room and go back to previous room the item is back.
so the problem is we initialize the FXML file anew each time.
the way we change rooms:

a small edit:

```
public class StartGame extends Main {
    @FXML private Button start;

    @FXML
    public void onStart(MouseEvent event) {

        //works this way
        Parent loader = XMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("station.fxml"));
        // does not work O_o
        Parent loader = getScene("station");


        Stage stage = (Stage) start.getScene().getWindow();

        stage.setScene(new Scene(loader, 731, 439))
    }
}
```

```
public class Main extends Application {
    HashMap<String, Parent> scenes = new HashMap<>();

    public void start(Stage stage) {
        Parent station = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("station.fxml"));    
        scenes.put("station", station);
        
        Stage stage = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("startGame.fxml"));
        stage.show();
    }

    public Parent getScene(String roomName) {
        return this.scenes.get(roomName);
    }
}
```

but when i try to use the `getScene()` method i get all sorts of erros, is this a smart way of trying to save changes when switching between FXML files or is there a better way?..that actually works

Comment: " so the problem is we initialize the FXML file anew each time". So don't. Just load the FXML files once and store the different `Parent`s somewhere.

Comment: @James_D you should post this as an answer, I don't want to answer by just stealing your comment.

Comment: @ChristianO. It's not a complete answer though, because the question is not complete. The OP basically says they tried to do that "but get all sorts of errors". So, obviously the question is really about fixing those errors, which no-one can do without knowing what they are and without a [mre].

Comment: edited code a bit...hopefully a bit more clear this time

Comment: Why is your controller a subclass of your `Application` class? In any case, when you call `getScene("station")` in the controller, it will return `null`, so presumably "all sorts of errors" (did you even bother reading the stack trace, by the way?) includes a `NullPointerException`. You only ever put `station` in the map in the instance of `Main` created when the application starts, not in the instance of the controller.

Comment: @James_D that's what I'm trying to do with the hashmap, but for some reason they won't load that way...

Comment: As I just explained in my last comment.

Comment: @James_D thx for the comment I think I can work with that, only been coding for 2-3months now so everything is new and only got introduced to javafx 2 weeks ago, so it's all a learning curve 

Comment: @James_D Remember that the code example does not illustrate the full code. Your comments also do not help to clarify the question further or get closer to an answer. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work

Comment: @DibloDk Yeah, fair enough. The OP should post a [mre]; I would argue though that comments pointing them in the direction of the cause of the issue would make it easier to do that.

Comment: - Yes. Sorry it was my intention to write comment and not comments.